# How to I access a page level (local) javascript variable in a greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I just want my GM script to do a window.alert(foo) where foo is equal to a local javascript variable within the page.

Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
alert(unsafeWindow.foo);
```